# How to retrieve image from firebase based on click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase for my android app. I have uploaded few images in Storage section of firebase and displayed in listview. Now when I click on particular image of recyclerview, I want to move to next activity and show the image which I clicked on in imageview of next activity. How to retrieve that particular image? Please help.

I have created a photos folder in storage of my firebase and all images are stored in that folder.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
    public static final String FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY = "friendly_msg_length";

    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        // Initialize Firebase components
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("photos");

        // Initialize references to views
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
        List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message, friendlyMessages);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

        // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
        mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });

        // Enable Send button when there's text to send
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);

                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };

        // Create Remote Config Setting to enable developer mode.
        // Fetching configs from the server is normally limited to 5 requests per hour.
        // Enabling developer mode allows many more requests to be made per hour, so developers
        // can test different config values during development.
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .build();
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);

        // Define default config values. Defaults are used when fetched config values are not
        // available. Eg: if an error occurred fetching values from the server.
        Map<String, Object> defaultConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
        defaultConfigMap.put(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY, DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT);
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultConfigMap);
        fetchConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Get a reference to store file at chat_photos/<FILENAME>
            StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            // Upload file to Firebase Storage
            photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            // Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it to the database
                            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUrl.toString());
                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
        mMessageAdapter.clear();
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_menu:
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        mMessageAdapter.clear();
        detachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(friendlyMessage);
                }

                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }

    private void detachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener != null) {
            mMessagesDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mChildEventListener);
            mChildEventListener = null;
        }
    }

    // Fetch the config to determine the allowed length of messages.
    public void fetchConfig() {
        long cacheExpiration = 3600; // 1 hour in seconds
        // If developer mode is enabled reduce cacheExpiration to 0 so that each fetch goes to the
        // server. This should not be used in release builds.
        if (mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()) {
            cacheExpiration = 0;
        }
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        // Make the fetched config available
                        // via FirebaseRemoteConfig get<type> calls, e.g., getLong, getString.
                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();

                        // Update the EditText length limit with
                        // the newly retrieved values from Remote Config.
                        applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // An error occurred when fetching the config.
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error fetching config", e);

                        // Update the EditText length limit with
                        // the newly retrieved values from Remote Config.
                        applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Apply retrieved length limit to edit text field. This result may be fresh from the server or it may be from
     * cached values.
     */
    private void applyRetrievedLengthLimit() {
        Long friendly_msg_length = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY);
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(friendly_msg_length.intValue())});
        Log.d(TAG, FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY + " = " + friendly_msg_length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your complete code for best understanding. Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look.I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Implement an onclick listener for the recycleview and pass the image URL in intent on the new activity as follows

```
intent.putExtra("IMAGE_URL", "url of the image");
startActivity(intent);
```

Use the following code to get the URL on the second activity

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE_URL");
```

Comment: How to get the image url of the clicked image from Firebase storage beacuse user can choose any image from firebase storage

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the image a download URL is created by Firebase.
From your code, it's clear that you have the image download URL as created by Firebase.

Even if you dont have the Download URL you can get it using the

```
storageReferenceObj.getDownloadUrl();
```

In order to load that image in an ImageView you can use the Picasso library.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

replace the URL with your download URL and specify your image view. But First add this line to your Gradle file in order to include Picasso library.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

More info: http://square.github.io/picasso/